# Importing file in react-ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm importing the file in another component but getting error
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './NavButton' in 'C:\Users\nidhi\Documents\my-projects\estate-website\src\components'

here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ListIcon from '@mui/icons-material/List';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import NavButton from './NavButton';

import logo from '../Images/logo.png';
import { 
  Box,
  Typography,
  ThemeProvider 
} from '@mui/material';


const Header = () => {

  return (
    <Box  >
      <Box
      margin='auto'
      height='100%'
      display='flex'
      justifyContent='space-between'
      alignItems='center'
      padding='0px 10px'
      sx={{
        width:{lg:'90%',md:'95%'}
      }}
      >
        <Box
        display='flex'
        justifyContent='space-between'
        className='nav-menu'
        alignItems='center'
        gap='2rem'>
          <NavButton/>
        </Box>
        {/* // */}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I want to import the files but not able.

Comment: do you have a default export in NavButton?

Comment: Also post contents of `NavButton.js`. Is it in the same directory?

Comment: i have default export and navbutton.tsx in same directory